# TapGesture to get recognize ony on openflowview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I am using openflow library in my project.There is requirement that when I tap that image shown in openflow another view controller will be opened.

My problem is I made a tapGestureRecognizer but is it getting called on all my buttons in that view and every other thing.
I want that tapGestureRecognizer to get initiated when tap on the image on open flow,no where else.
Please help me.I am stuck here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Only add the tap gesture to the view you want it on.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];

//openFlowImageView is the view that you want the tap to work on.
[openFlowImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

Comment: there is no view named openFlowImageView in openflowview.m

Comment: well whatever the name of your image view is, replace "openFlowImageView" with it.